# Item after current item in list

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am currently working with a link list of items. I am aware of `LinkedList<T>()` but I am implementing this on my own for learning purposes. I have created an `Add` function that appends an item to the end of the list. Now I am struggling with my `Insert` function which should append an item after the currently pointed to item. Instead it is displaying error when calling `Insert();` `Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state`. Any ideas how to insert an item after the current pointed to item? (I am displaying the currently pointed item in a label called `labelSpecificTree`)

**Code**

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
            public FruitTrees Insert(int Position)
            {                    
                FruitTrees current = First;

                for (int i = 0; i < Position && current != null; i++)
                {
                    current = current.Next;
                }
                return current;    
            }                

    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to work on reducing the code to the smallest possible example that can replicate the problem, instead of just dumping the whole thing and saying "fix it".

Comment: Umm not going to fight about the close, but as a clue, get rid of all that index stuff. Find the Item you want to insert after, create the newitem, set it's Next to that of teh item you found and found's to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking.

But if you need to insert an item after a given list item:

```
public Insert(Item newItem, Item refItem) {
  newItem.Next = refItem.Next;
  refItem.Next = newItem;
}
```